# Automatically update array of objects value when typing

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, dom-events

I want to update array of object value triggered by `onChange` event in React. In this case, I want to update "NOTE" data depends on input (depends on DETAIL_REQUEST_ID). When I input for the first time, "NOTE" has updated well. but after entering the next data, previous data is lost.

Here's my code, sorry for my bad English. Hope you get what I mean.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const dummy = [
    { DETAIL_REQUEST_ID: 1, STATUS: "REJECT", NOTE: "" },
    { DETAIL_REQUEST_ID: 2, STATUS: "REJECT", NOTE: "" },
    { DETAIL_REQUEST_ID: 3, STATUS: "REJECT", NOTE: "" },
  ];

  const handleBtn = () => {
    console.log("DATA: ", data);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    let newArr = [...dummy];
    const updatedArr = newArr.map(el => {
      if (id === el.DETAIL_REQUEST_ID) {
        el = { ...el, NOTE: e.target.value };
      }
      return el;
    });
    setData(updatedArr);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Detail Request Id</th>
          <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
        {dummy.map(val => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{val.DETAIL_REQUEST_ID}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, val.DETAIL_REQUEST_ID)} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </table>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleBtn}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basing your state updates off the same constant `dummy` object each time. This resets the state. You should use `data` instead.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const dummy = [
    { DETAIL_REQUEST_ID: 1, STATUS: "REJECT", NOTE: "" },
    { DETAIL_REQUEST_ID: 2, STATUS: "REJECT", NOTE: "" },
    { DETAIL_REQUEST_ID: 3, STATUS: "REJECT", NOTE: "" },
  ];

  // use the dummy object to initialize the state <============= !!
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummy);

  const handleBtn = () => {
    console.log("DATA: ", data);
  };

  const handleChange = (e, id) => {
    // use the actual state to base your changes off of <============= !!
    let newArr = [...data];
    const updatedArr = newArr.map(el => {
      if (id === el.DETAIL_REQUEST_ID) {
        el = { ...el, NOTE: e.target.value };
      }
      return el;
    });
    setData(updatedArr);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Detail Request Id</th>
          <th>Note</th>
        </tr>
        {/*
            render the actual state (using data, not dummy) <============= !!
        */}
        {data.map(val => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{val.DETAIL_REQUEST_ID}</td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, val.DETAIL_REQUEST_ID)} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
      </table>
      <button type="submit" onClick={handleBtn}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```